# display two database table data in a single html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 tables viz Customer, Project and Payment. Logically Customer should pay based on the project but in real scenario the payment system is different. They pay in random amounts. Project and Payment are child table of Customer. Both Project and Payment have customer id

**Customer table**

```
CUSTID              CUSTNAME             CUSTADDRESS
1                   XYZ                  ABC
2                   IJK                  ABCD
```

**Project Table**

```
PROJID      PROJNAME         AMOUNT    CUS_ID
1           Project 1        10000     1
2           Project 2        5000      1
3           Project 3        11000     1
4           Project 4        2000      2  
5           Project 5        3000      1
```

**Payment Table**

```
PAYID       PAID          CUST_ID
1           5000          1
2           7000          1
3           4000          2
4           1000          1
```

Now I want to display project and payment details of each customer in a same html table. I want the payment be reflected based on the project. If the first project amount is 5000 and first payment is 7000 then I want the payment to be displayed in the second project because 5000 is the applicable amount for the first project and remaining 2000 can be applied for second project provided the second project amount is greater than 2000. Otherwise if second project amount is only 1000 then the payment should be displayed in third project as 1000 is for second project and 1000 leftover goes for third project so on and so forth. If the project amount and payment amount is equal or project amount greater than payment then the payment should be reflected on the same row.

How can I achieve something like below or can anybody recommend me a better solution to achieve displaying data from two disjoint database table into one html table.

```
PROJID   PROJNAME    AMOUNT     CUS_ID     PAYID
1        Project 1   10000      1
2        Project 2   5000       1          2 (for payment 7000+2000<11000)
3        Project 3   11000      1          1 (for payment 5000, left 2000)
5        Project 5   3000       1
```

Comment: These two databases are on the same server right?

Comment: @Surabhil Sergy i tried the joins but that gives me duplicate records

Comment: @Reagan Gallant Yes, both the tables are in the same server and same database

Comment: @raaman You need a Project_Payment table with Proj Id, custId, datetime which can be updated using a trigger whenever a payment is made.

Comment: Thank you @Reagan Gallant for the suggestion but infact i have implemented that solution already. For that i've to apply a payment to one project which is not very correct in my context. My situation is very odd as i have to book the payment as per the applicable amount from the project.